# Complexity of ANOTHER HAMILTONIAN CIRCUIT problem

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, hamiltonian-circuit

All references I find about the ANOTHER HAMILTONIAN CIRCUIT problem:

> Given a graph and a hamiltonian circuit on it, is there another
>   hamiltonian circuit on it?

I was trying to reduce it to the hamiltonian circuit problem but I always need to add too many or too few circuits to the original one.

Am I going through the good direction? It seems to be very simple...

**Edit**

Papadimitriou's complexity book refers to its theorem 17.5 for the inspiration for this problem.

I think that a good way for the solution is to consider the graph proposed in Papadimitrious'[image]

One can for each node of the original graph, transform to the graph shown at the left image. Then, one can connect all these new graphs using the poles N and S and thus obtains a hamiltonian circuit. Then, one uses W and E to connect vertex that were connected in the original graph. In principle, one could connect W with W and E with E.

I only have one more doubt, what happens if the original graph is just a segment, that is, two vertex with a edge between them. My construction would give an extra hamiltonian circuit going from W1->E1->E2->W2->W1 even if the original one didn't have one!

Can you find any other counterexample? This was the solution given in my course and it seems to be partly wrong...

Comment: You need to reduce the Hamiltonian Circuit problem (or some other NP-hard problem) *to* this problem: That is, *if* you had a magic device for solving ANOTHER HAMILTONIAN CIRCUIT quickly, could you solve other hard problems with it too?

Comment: I take back my earlier claim that there was a trivial reduction!  I don't see any obvious way.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I updated with what seems to be the correct reduction but still have doubts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This result is proved in the senior thesis [The complexities of puzzles, cross sum and their another solution problems (ASP)](http://www-imai.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~seta/paper/senior_thesis/seniorthesis.pdf) by Takahiro Seta.

The systematic study of ASPs was initiated by Ueda and Nagao in their paper [NP-completeness Results for NONOGRAM via
Parsimonious Reductions](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.57.5277&rep=rep1&type=pdf). See also Takayuki Yato's master thesis, [Complexity and completeness of finding another solution and its application to puzzles](http://www-imai.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~yato/data2/MasterThesis.pdf).

Comment: Yes, they prove a stronger result.